# XPath, using xlink:href to load multiple elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm working on an app that uses apache-commons-configuration and XPath to parse loads of XML files. No DTDs or Schemas are used, so it's all pretty loose.

If the app gets this config:

```
<SessionManager>
 <Session ... />
 <Sessopm ... />
</SessionManager>
```

it successfully creates two Session objects. So I know that the app is written in such a way that it's looking for multiples.

Now, instead, if I use the xlin:href to reference another file like this:

```
<SessionManager>
  <Session xlink:href="file.xml://Session"/>
</SessionManager>
```

and put the following in file.xml:

```
<Anything>
  <Session .../>
  <Session .../>
</Anything>
```

It only loads the first one.

Now, I thought the "//Session" syntax should give me all the  elements in the file. I can only assume the xlink:href is messing with things.

Any help appreciated.
Regards, Ian

Answer (score 0):

I still dont really know why this just doesnt work, but I've managed to work around the problem by linking to the parent object - in my example, the

```
<Anything/>
```

element